# Multiplicación de Decimales

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es que al momento de hacer la multiplicación me lo redondea y quiero que me tome decimal .00 o .20, tanto en la columna total como en la suma final .
En la base de datos los decimales se muestran bien pero al momento de realizar la operación no. ,
Tambien intenté l osiguiente:

```
$products = $con->query("select id , name, cast(price as decimal (10,2)),id_imagen,categoria from product where id=$c[product_id]  ");
$total = $con->query("select id , name, cast(price as decimal (10,2)) ,id_imagen,categoria from product where id=$c[product_id] ");
```

Pero me manda ceros la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Podrían comentarme como puedo resolver lo siguiente? , gracias

Comment: Por favor cambia la captura de imagen de código por el texto del mismo. Así no se puede reproducir para hacer pruebas y es más complicado de analizar para encontrar errores. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Podrías usar [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php). Sería más o menos así: `$valFinal=number_format($valUno*$valDos,2);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo , me funcionó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me tope con un caso similar al tulló, para ello yo utilice, en lugar de la función `cast`, la función `round`, con el bien entendido que en mi la base de datos, para no tener problemas, el campo colocato en `float`.

```
$products = $con->query("select id , name, round(price,2),id_imagen,categoria from product where id=$c[product_id]  ");
$total = $con->query("select id , name, round(price, 2) ,id_imagen,categoria from product where id=$c[product_id]");
```